# Find a single value in array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a noob when it comes to JS and am trying to figure out how to return a single value instead of an object when using the .find() function.

Example:

```js
var obj = [
    { name: 'Max', age: 23 },
    { name: 'John', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Caley', age: 18 }
];
 
var found = obj.find(e => e.name === 'John');
console.log(found);
```

This will output `{ name: 'John', age: 20 }`

I want it to output John's age (ie: `20`) as a string.

What am I missing?

Comment: *What am I missing* --> `.age`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple add `?.age` to your `found` variable.

```js
var obj = [
    { name: 'Max', age: 23 },
    { name: 'John', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Caley', age: 18 }
];
 
var found = obj.find(e => e.name === 'John')?.age; // Using ?. incase value isnt found.
console.log(found);
```

You also mention you need it as a string, you can do achieve by wrapping the `found` var in the `String` function like so...

```js
var obj = [
    { name: 'Max', age: 23 },
    { name: 'John', age: 20 },
    { name: 'Caley', age: 18 }
];
 
var found = String(obj.find(e => e.name === 'John')?.age);
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

.find function return you an object so you can just do something like this

```
var age = obj.find(e => e.name === "John").age
```